# Join array by character?

Tags: ruby, arrays

If I have an array:

```
array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

And I want to slice it by 3 into 2 arrays, and then flatten them but before I flatten them, add a character like a `/`, how would I do it?

I've tried the following which joins after each sub-array not after the nth value of the slice:

```
array.each_slice(5).map.join("/")
```

Is it possible to use regex, as in after 5 counts of `\w`?

Comment: what should the result look like?

Comment: "flatten" them? What do you mean, by this? As the Ruby method ".flatten" is applied to nested arrays, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: Once I slice it into multiple arrays, it will be an array of arrays, which I can flatten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.each_slice(3).map{|x| x.unshift('/') }.flatten[1..-1]
# => ["a", "b", "c", "/", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to get ["a","b","c","/","d","e","f"]

```
(array.each_slice(3).inject([]) {|res, item| res << '/' unless res.empty?; res << item }).flatten
# => ["a", "b", "c", "/", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.join.gsub(/(\w{3})/, '\1/').chomp('/').split('')
```

Comment: With `array = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]` your code will return `["a", "a", "b", "/", "b", "c", "c", "/", "d", "d"]`. Looks like this is not what OP wanted.